# GMap.NET - set amount of markers depending on the zoom level (cluster marker)

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, google-maps-markers, gmap.net

How are handles a huge amount of markers in GMAP.net?

e.g. I want to show locations (pictures , restaurants etc.) and when I zoom out I want to show a clustered marker with a picture and the amount of markers in the cluster.
e.g. citiy of Berlin with a marker and 500 restaurants and when I zoom in, the 500 locations are shown (all the .

Is there something like a auto clustering depending on the zoom level?
Or are there separate layers, which I can attach to specific zoom levels?

When I zoom out into the world I cannot add tenthousends of markers, Gmanp.Net lags and freezes. I need to show cluster markers!

Or Ist there a other map (C# WPF) which can handle this easy?

What is the prefered handling here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some research I found out.
The WPF version has none of the features I require and asked (but the Winforms version has some of them) and have to implement them by my own.

[Overlays in GMap.Net Wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922211/overlays-in-gmap-net-wpf)

[How to resize custom markers depending on zoom level in GMap.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574822/how-to-resize-custom-markers-depending-on-zoom-level-in-gmap-net)